# Why are some questions removed from the HNQ list very quickly?

Tags: support, hot-network-questions

I've noticed that some questions don't last very long in the [HNQ list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?page=1). For example, this question, [Where does the "dysfunctional or broken" meaning of the word "demic" come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591002/where-does-the-dysfunctional-or-broken-meaning-of-the-word-demic-come-from) or this one, [What is the meaning of "beggar" in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591033/what-is-the-meaning-of-beggar-in-this-context). Both of them became hot network posts, but didn't last very long in the HNQ list (you can also judge by the number of views on both questions), just about a day or so (instead of the usual three days).

As far as I know, only moderators can remove questions out of the HNQ list. Is there some other factor that I'm missing?

Comment: The two examples provided does not appear to be removed from HNQ by mods.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. I'm talking about questions which have not been removed by moderators, but are still removed from the HNQ list after a day or so. The two examples should have been in the HNQ list right now, but they aren't.

Comment: @Justin HNQ status is self-sustaining. If after some time on the HNQ, interest in the form of votes, answers, and comments (maybe? not sure) isn’t sustain, the Qs are delisted. The opposite is also true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those questions/answers had just enough upvotes to get onto the HNQ, but didn't get many (net) upvotes after that. Age makes a question less hot, so a Q&A needs to keep collecting upvotes to compensate. (New answers that collect upvotes also help a lot.)

Make sure you're upvoting good posts, even if a few other people already have. (And also downvote if a post really is bad.)

See also the [HNQ formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/323179) on MSE.